# How to show that $ \|X\|_2^2=tr(X^2)=\frac1n \sum \lambda_i^2 $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis

[image]

I am reading this result. For Frobenius norm of a symmetric matrix, we know that
$$
\|X\|_2^2=\sum_{1\le i,j\le n} X_{ij}^2=tr(XX^T)=tr(X^2)
$$

But why does it say that the above equality is equal to $\frac1n tr(X^2)$? Also, how to show that
$$
\|X\|_2^2=tr(X^2)=\frac1n \sum \lambda_i^2
$$
where $\lambda_i$ are eigenvalues of $X$.

Comment: What did you try to do?

Comment: The $\tfrac{1}{n}$ is because of the word "normalized." Try to be consistent about whether you're using $\tfrac{1}{n}$ or not, lest you get errors. To get the sum over eigenvalues expression, use the spectral theorem (as the hint says).